# php call c++ socket function cause Permission denied error

Tags: php, c++, sockets, permissions

I have a php code:

```
<?php
$res = "";
exec("./a.out>temp", $res);
print_r(error_get_last());
print_r($res);
?>
```

a.out is a simple c++ program creating a socket. when I call this php code from browser an error of "Permission denied" is printed in the "temp" file.

I know this is a problem related to the right of apache user, but how to solve it?

Note: I have redirected the stderr into the "temp" file so that I can see what is wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the 'www' (or apache) users permissions are the problem.

Another option is that the socket already exists . .

Perhaps it is a problem with SE linux (if you are on linux)

`/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1`

Source: http://www.rkrishardy.com/2009/12/permission-denied-13-when-opening-socket-in-php-apache/

On a side note, php can do socket stuff as-well . .

Comment: when access from browser, the user is apache not www. I also believe it is permissions problem, but just do not known how to solve

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
chmod 755 a.out
chmod 666 temp
```

Comment: Try this 'echo "dev" > temp', is this execute from web?

Answer (score 1):

Change your user to the one which is executing your apache. For example like this:

```
su www-data
```

And then execute the command again.